# How do I encrypt a whole partition mounted at /?

Tags: encryption, 18.04, partitioning

`/home` encryption [is not available in the Ubuntu installer 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029249/how-to-encrypt-home-on-ubuntu-18-04#)

I still want to protect my data, and the workaround is to encrypt the whole partition.

How do I encrypt a whole partition mounted at / in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Encryption of / makes it unbootable.