# Upgrading ubuntu 16.04lts to 18.04lts; booting stops at console msg: Starting Update UTMP

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, console

Around Aug 15,2018, I upgraded from 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS using, IIRC, the
gui shown here:

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.85153881.1518174303.1535755443-1996780387.1511607668#3

I also remember making some change which enabling printing to the console extensive boot info.

However, when booting, the console messages *sometimes* stop at:

[ OK ] Started Console Manager.
tion 45s after completed startup.     Starting Update UTMP about System  Runlevel...

but other times (most recently) the console boot msgs stop at:

[ OK ] Started Daily apt download activities

I've googled and read and tried several solutions, none of which work.
In particular, I've tried solutions posted on following urls:

[Upgrade from 14.04 "Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/799036/upgrade-from-14-04-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes)

[While booting stops at Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887103/while-booting-stops-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes)

as well as solutions posted on several other urls. I've also got a text
file logging my attempts, but that's > 800 lines long.  A link to the
log file is here:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pHvdcrNfKw/

At around 800 of that file, it shows I no longer have a write
home directory.  That may have something to do with the
(probably rash) attempt at avoiding the login msgs containing:

Could not find key

That attempt involved simple renaming instead of deleting
the ~/.Private and ~/.ecryptfs files.

Are the files in my home directory lost forever (except for the backups)?

On yesterday, was able to recover my home directory by reinstalling
ecryptfs-utils and then using ecryptfs-mount-private; however, still
getting the message (in /var/kernel.log) about not finding key and still
no gui login screen appears.

Tried solutions described from here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1718658

in particular the `keyctl link @u @s` command, but that made no difference.

On 2018-09-13, found this page:

[How to Encrypt /home on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029249/how-to-encrypt-home-on-ubuntu-18-04/1031509)

which, in a comment by SunnyDaze, said:

can't mount it new because "encrypt home folder" option is gone now
  from the installer?  We can't even log in.

which sounds a lot like my problem.  Will look further on that page for
answers.

Comment: I recommend posting your log file on [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and adding a link to the paste in this post.

Answer (score 0):

After a regular update my UBUNTU 16.04 LTS asked me if I wanted to install UBUNTU 18.04 LTS. I agreed, and installation started. There were no problems until booting stopped at the console message mentioned above.
Using GRUB V2.02, during the next try I selected "**ubuntu - advanced options - recovery mode**" from the menus. The screens switched to VGA resolution 640*480, and boot continued until recovery menu showed up. When I selected "Resume normal boot", the system booted without problems and started up finally with the correct screen resolution.
It seems to me that the reduced VGA resolution during boot time in recovery mode is the workaround for this error.

Comment: See next comments (don't know how to delete comment).

Comment: Thanks Kurt; however, I tried that, but after selecting "Resume normal boot', the console displayed messages quickly (I assume boot messages), and then redisplayed the menu with "Resume normal boot".  Repeated that selection.  Still no change.  I'm lost :(

Comment: Kurt, I should also add that before I followed your suggestions, I'd solved the problem about no home directory by using ecrypt-mount-private and rebooting.  I've no idea whether that change is relevant.