# ecryptfs: mount: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, encryption, ecryptfs

I installed `ecryptfs-utils` in my new `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils
```

Then I set up a `Private` directory as described in a [wiki.archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Encrypting_a_data_directory) documentation:

```
$ ecryptfs-setup-private --nopwcheck --noautomount
```

Then I made a recovery of all my data with the `Backups` utility inside the Private directory.
Everything seemed to work fine but when I powered on my machine this morning I wasn't able to decrypt my Private directory:

```
$ ecryptfs-mount-private 
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [fd7bf4e96709610d] into the user session keyring
mount: No such file or directory
```

ecryptfs failed to mount the Private directory.
I read the similar topic [ecryptfs-mount-private failure in Ubuntu 18.04: mount: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074753/ecryptfs-mount-private-failure-in-ubuntu-18-04-mount-no-such-file-or-directory) but the solution provided by Gregor did not work for me. Any idea on how can I fix this issue?

This is the output of `keyctl show`:

```
$ keyctl show
Session Keyring
 129407649 --alswrv   1000  1000  keyring: _ses
 779489152 ----s-rv      0     0   \_ user: invocation_id
```

The problem was reported as a bug at [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/1788465).