# Cannot run docker on an encrypted filesystem

Tags: 18.04, encryption, docker

I encrypted my home directory using the instructions specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029249/how-to-encrypt-home-on-ubuntu-18-04/1029330) (specifically the fscrypt guide with the exception that I set a different unlock phrase to my password deliberately). However, I have problems starting my docker services:

```
service_a         | /bin/sh: 1: /code/app/bin/celery_worker.py: Required key not available
service_b         | standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "required key not available"
service_c         | standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "required key not available"
service_d         | standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "required key not available"
```

Is there an extra step I need to do in order for them to access my home directory? Wondering if this is not related to [this](https://github.com/google/fscrypt/issues/128).

EDIT: A maintainer left a reply to my comment there for those interested, seems like this is quite some way from being fixed unfortunately.