# Does Chromium web browser store passwords more securely than Firefox?

Tags: firefox, password, security, chromium, keyrings

As far as I know Chromium uses some keyring, so if you for example make Ubuntu not ask password on login, Chromium will ask you for password when it is launched. Is it different when comparing to Firefox? Are passwords stored as plain-text? Do I need additional master password? If I switch user, can the other user see my passwords? (At least there may be a problem with [guest user](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1742912).)

Answer (score 1):

Chromium integrates with Gnome Keyring. So you have to (re-)enter your password when starting the browser to be able to access your stored passwords. Firefox doesn't integrate with Gnome Keyring, however:

- Firefox doesn't store your passwords in plain text.
- Firefox saves the passwords in your profile, so different user accounts on your PC shouldn't be able to view your passwords.

Take into account though, that keeping any personal data safe (inlcuding the Firefox profile stored in your home dir) is extremely difficult as soon as others have physical access to your PC. If you are worried about that, make sure to have a strong password on your user account, set a master password in Firefox and think about [encrypting your home directory](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031509/21008).

Comment: I do not have to re-enter password for Chromium, if I enter password on login.

Comment: Yes. If you enter your password on logon the Gnome keyring is automatically unlocked. If you use autologin, the keyring is locked and you need to enter the password, when an application (i.e. Chromium) tries to access it.