# How do I automatically mount LUKS drives upon login?

Tags: mount, encryption, automount, luks

I have three hard drives in my PC, all encrypted with LUKS. When booting from the primary drive, I enter my password to unlock the drive and log into Ubuntu 18.04. From the file browser, I can click on the other encrypted drives and they automatically mount - but I have to click them to achieve this. I would prefer it if these drives automatically mounted from inside Ubuntu. I followed the instructions on this page (https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile) and Ubuntu failed to boot - I had to use the terminal in emergency mode to revert my changes. Can someone please give me advice on how to get this working?

Screenshot of gparted - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugJvC.jpg

I originally setup LUKS on the non-system drives through the Ubuntu Disks tool.

Here is my original /etc/crypttab file:

```
sda5_crypt UUID=69d81a7b-ca41-43b6-8731-556c93ca2337 none luks,discard
```

Here is my edited /etc/crypttab file which won't boot:

```
sda5_crypt UUID=69d81a7b-ca41-43b6-8731-556c93ca2337 none luks,discard
sdc_crypt      /dev/sdc  /root/keyfile  luks
sdd_crypt      /dev/sdd  /root/keyfile  luks
```

Here is my original /etc/fs/tab file:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=25153066-2214-41ef-bf5b-fbe2224ea456 /boot           ext4    defaults        0    $
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Here is my edited /etc/fstab file which won't boot:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=25153066-2214-41ef-bf5b-fbe2224ea456 /boot           ext4    defaults        0    $
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
/dev/mapper/sdc_crypt  /media/p/Data1     ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/sdd_crypt  /media/p/Data2     ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the app Gparted showing the three hard drives and then upload the picture to imgur.com. Finally, put a link of the uploaded image in the question above? Also add in the question how you originally set up LUKS for the two other encrypted drives. Copy and paste the contents of the file `/etc/crypttab` in the question. Then format the pasted text as code using the { } icon above the **Edit Question** window.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1020390/how-do-i-auto-mount-luks-partition looks like it might have a similar solution.